# Assign Value to Diagonal Entries of Matrix

Tags: r, matrix, assign

I need to access and assign single slots of an m*n matrix inside a for loop. The code so far:

```
rowCount <- 9
similMatrix = matrix(nrow = rowCount - 1, ncol = rowCount)
show(similMatrix)
for(i in (rowCount - 1)){
  for (j in rowCount)
    if (i == j){
      similMatrix[i == j] <- 0;
    }
}
show(similMatrix)
```

so if i = j the NA value in the matrix needs to be replaced with 0.

Comment: are you not getting desired output?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For the purpose of setting the "diagonal" elements to zero you have already been given an answer but I wonder if you were hoping for something more general. The reasons for lack of success with that code were two-fold: the construction of your indices were flawed and the indexing was wrong. This would have succeeded:

```
for(i in 1:(rowCount - 1)){  # need an expression that retruns a sequence
  for (j in 1:rowCount)      # ditto
    if (i == j){
      similMatrix[i,j] <- 0;  # need to index the matrix with two element if using i,j
    }
}
#----------
> show(similMatrix)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
[1,]    0   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
[2,]   NA    0   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
[3,]   NA   NA    0   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
[4,]   NA   NA   NA    0   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
[5,]   NA   NA   NA   NA    0   NA   NA   NA   NA
[6,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    0   NA   NA   NA
[7,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    0   NA   NA
[8,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    0   NA
```

But resorting to loops in R is generally considered a last resort (sometimes for the wrong reasons.) There is a much more compact way of doing the same "loop" operation and it generalizes more widely than just setting the diagonal.

```
similMatrix[ row(similMatrix) == col(similMatrix) ] <- 0
> similMatrix
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
[1,]    0   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
[2,]   NA    0   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
[3,]   NA   NA    0   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
[4,]   NA   NA   NA    0   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
[5,]   NA   NA   NA   NA    0   NA   NA   NA   NA
[6,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    0   NA   NA   NA
[7,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    0   NA   NA
[8,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    0   NA
```

If you wanted to set the subdiagonal to zero you could just use:

```
similMatrix[ row(similMatrix)-1 == col(similMatrix) ] <- 0
```

You can avoid generating the extra row and col matrices using this:

```
 mind <- min( dim(similMatrix) )
 # avoid going outside dimensions if not symmetric
 similMatrix[ cbind( seq(maxd),seq(maxd) ) <- 0
```

Comment: I imagine `row(mat)` and `col(mat)` will generate two matrices, wouldn't this mean that we are tripling
memory consumption here? If `mat` happened
to be big, I guess this can cause problems.

Comment: Quite right. I didn't see any warnings that these were big matrices. The "compactness" I was offering was in expression, but as you point out this may not be compact in memory footprint. One can imagine using `similMatrix[cbind(1:(rowCount - 1), 1:(rowCount - 1)] <- 0` and I'm guessing it would perform in a superior fashion for both memory and speed. I'm thinking that might have an even lower footprint that the `mat[diag(mat)] <-0` approach.

Answer (score 40):

You want the function `diag<-`

```
m <- matrix(1:12, nrow=3)
m
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    4    7   10
[2,]    2    5    8   11
[3,]    3    6    9   12

diag(m) <- 0
m
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    4    7   10
[2,]    2    0    8   11
[3,]    3    6    0   12
```

Comment: Where is that `delete-my-answer-and-upvote-the-other` button?

Comment: thanks, it works, but how can i now assign a value for lets say m[1, 2] ?